# How can I verify that a git project's release branch's fixes have all been merged into master?

Tags: git

I have a git repository for a project at work. Each time we release a version of our software, we create a release branch for it. There's a release1.0 branch, a release 1.1 branch, etc. When we need to create a hotfix for that release, we commit the fix to that release branch, and then we merge that fix into our master development branch.

Sometimes we forget that last step in our rush to fix a production bug, and then a new release goes out without the hotfix for our previous problem.

Is there an easy git command that checks to see if all our our release branches have been merged into master, and if not, which commits in which branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `git branch --no-merged master`. This should list all branches that haven't been merged into `master`.

Another approach is to type `git log master..branch`, which will show empty results if branch is merged into master, and will otherwise present a list of unmerged commits.

Comment: Oooo, that's useful!  Is there a way to ask for a list of specific commits that haven't been merged in?

Comment: If you want a list of commits in branch `other` that haven't been merged into `master`, the simplest thing to do is `git log master..other`.

Comment: Well, wait, that makes this even easier!  If git log origin/master..origin/releaseX is blank, then it's merged. Otherwise it's a list of missing commits, right?

Comment: @CaptainAwesomePants: Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: @CaptainAwesomePants: To be specific, `git log foo..bar` means "show all commits in `bar` that aren't in `foo`", so if that list is empty, then that means `foo` contains all commits from `bar`, which means `bar` was merged into `foo` at some point.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'm going to write a kick-ass little script that will email people saying "Your commit, X, is not merged into mainline." Thanks!